# Unable to edit address from company page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have standard company has many addresses case, where in my company model I have this :

```
has_many :company_addresses
accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_addresses, allow_destroy: true
```

In my company address model I have this :

```
  belongs_to :company, counter_cache: true
  validates :city, :zip, :street, :country, presence: true
```

Now when I try to update the actual address via company:

```
company_address = company.company_addresses.first
company.assign_attributes(company_addresses_attributes: [id: company_address.id, street: 'New Street'])
company.save!
```

The actual address object does not change, why is this? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you have an error in your server. include it to get help.

Comment: Similar scenario worked for me. You should have some errors/warnings/etc

Comment: You can just use `company.update!` instead of two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post the error message for getting better help. That's being said, I can see you added validations for `city`, `zip`, `street`, `country`. However, when assigning attributes with `company_addresses_attributes: [id: company_address.id, street: 'New Street']`, you have missed `city`, `zip`, `country`.

Again, can't be sure if this is the exact problem without seeing any actual errors. Try and let me know.